# How can I solve following query in Neo4j? List the Names of the projects belonging to department managed by employee “…….”

Tags: neo4j

List the Names of the projects belonging to department managed by employee

```
relations:
Works_in : employee works in a department
Has_acquired: employee has acquired a skill
Assigned_to : employee assigned to a project
Controlled_by: A project is controlled by a department
Project_manager : Employee is a project_manager of a Project
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is/are the error(s)? what is the expected result?

Comment: Agreed, please provide what queries you've tried so far, and why they don't fulfill your need. That will help us understand what part of the Cypher you're having trouble understanding. Also, please make it clear what the inputs are going to be supplied to the query.

Comment: create all labels and relationships

Comment: Not able able to fire query